# Retrieving the selected object in an NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking to retrieve the selected object in an NSOutlineView so I can see if the selected object has any children. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSOutlineView` inherits the `-selectedRow` method from `NSTableView`.  I suspect though, that what you really want is the current selection from whatever `NSController` is acting as your outline view's data source.

Comment: The NSTreeController? How would I retrieve that then?

Comment: If the NSTreeController is defined in your .xib/.nib file, you can create and link up an IBOutlet field in your controller to point to it and access it that way.

Comment: Go to the documentation for NSTreeController, and see the section labeled "Getting the Current Selection".

Comment: Ah, I see. So I can use Selected objects like `[treeController selectedObjects]`? But how would I then find the amount of children it has?

Comment: You need to read through the NSTreeController docs.  How you determine whether a given node is a leaf or has children depends on the model.